# Implementing jQuery autocomplete in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, qualtrics

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete text box for a question in my Qualtrics survey using jQuery. I realize this question was already asked/answered in another question(using jQuery for autocomplete in Qualtrics) on stackoverflow, but I tried following their solution and it did not work for me. (and I don't have enough rep points to comment on that question :(

The sample code I'm using is from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete; I copied this code into the look & feel section of Qualtrics:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>$.noConflict();</script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
    });
    </script>
```

and put the code below into the body of the question:

```
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
    });
```

I tried changing the selector from the sample code and the question body code to ('#QID15 .InputText), but that did not do anything.

Javascript and jQuery are uncharted territory for me and I do not know what to try next.
What am I missing with this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are doing the `$.noConflict()`. Also, you seem to be all over calling the jQuery library; sometimes using "$" and sometimes "jQuery". Also, if you are putting things in the `<head>` you should use `$(document).ready();`. Let's simplify...

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$("#tags").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="" id="tags" />
</body>
</html>
```

You're really going to want some style on that, but it should get you started.

Comment: Qualtrics uses Prototype.js for variable naming and they suggest declaring a $.noConflict() variable, so the survey system can differentiate jQuery. Please check out their webpage on how javascript works in Qualtrics: http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/javascript-in-qualtrics/ I don't need an actual textbox since Qualtrics' GUI creates that; I only need the autocomplete functionality in their textbox. I tested your code and it creates the textbox, but no autocomplete(something missing?)

Comment: I mentioned earlier that there's another post with the same problem and they solved it. I tried following it, but it still didn't work;The asker didn't mention what he changed from before. I come from a Python/R background and am trying to learn js and jQuery, but I don't know enough to work around things and need a direct solution. Maybe you or someone can please make sense of what they did in that post and how to utilize js in Qualtrics? Thank you for the response, it contributed to my learning of js and jQuery :)

Comment: If it helps, here's the template that Qualtrics uses to implement js into each question:                                                           `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
        {
 /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/




        });`